# I've made a question asking why OTServ - a huge MMORPG open-source community - has a problem with item cloning. Why it was closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Earlier I've posted [this question (link)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190628/dissertation-of-a-case-where-using-mysql-resulted-in-a-serious-scalability-probl) on Programmers Stack. Why was it closed and what can I do for it to be reopenned? Note: I've already made some edits taking in account the argumentation provided by the closers.

Comment: And ..... your question is back open.  Props for asking for guidance on how to revise your question.

Answer (score 4):

The original version of your question was very broad, and read more like a thesis than an actual question. It seemed like you've already made your mind on almost everything you were asking about, and if that's the case, why ask?

To make matters worse, your question is of the "foo vs bar" variety, and strictly speaking those are [off topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> and it is not about...
>
> - what language/technology you should learn next, **including which technology is better**,

Broad comparisons don't really work, we all have our favourites. If you don't give us enough parameters to make a sane comparison, the question is in danger of turning into yet another flame war. And yours almost did, the back and forth in the comments was getting out of hand. No one is to blame here, we all got caught up in the conversation.

Your edit was a step in the right direction, you removed your conclusions from the question, and it certainly reads more like a question now than a thesis. But you really need to do another update, and give us a few more details on the actual design.

With almost each one of your clarifying comments you revealed design idiosyncrasies, the project seems to have a very unique design. Every detail about it will help the community give you an actual answer, and not just opinions and speculation. You said in a comment that if you give us more details, the question would become "too localized". That's certainly a risk, but "too localized" is far better than "too broad/possibly flame-ish".

What I'd like to see in your question is:

- A very brief and very high level overview of OTServs design. Why, for example, is a crash so devastating, why isn't there any redundancy?
- A high level overview of the database schema, not just the table names. You mentioned in a comment that items don't have unique IDs, add that to the question.
- A brief outline of usage and traffic. Solutions for 500 concurrent users will be quite different from solutions for 5*10^6 concurrent users. Be precise and avoid words like "huge". A one million rows table is "huge" only if you haven't worked with billion rows tables.
- A somewhat detailed outline of what you need to save and when.
- Tell us what's beyond your control, what you can't possibly change.

All in all, it's a good question, but you've approached it from the wrong angle. Tell us what the problem is, and we'll do our best to help you solve it. But if you've already decided on a solution, then post it on your blog, not here.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions but how I could explain the entire OTServ design without making the question too big and localized?

Comment: @Dokkat Most design questions could be argued to be Too Localized if all the details are given.  We almost never close such questions as Too Localized.  We rarely use that reasoning and would much rather see specifics.

Comment: _"if you've already decided on a solution, then post it on your blog, not here"_ - wait a minute... there is a 100% legal and even welcomed [self-answer feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-answer/info "what's this"), isn't it a good fit for cases like that? Assuming of course that both question and answer comply with SE standards ([original revision](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/190628/1) of the question in question likely didn't)

Comment: @gnat - I think the OP is genuinely interested in other answers to their question that may (or may not) counter what they have discovered already.  You suggestion is valid though and the OP should consider adding an answer reflecting those observations.

Comment: @GlenH7 original rev text is quite vague, I can't tell if it supports your evaluation ("genuinely interested") or not. Anyway, I am generally not comfortable about statement like "got a solution => write to blog", when there is a self-answer feature

Comment: @gnat - my apologies there; I had only read latest which presents a much nicer PoV.  :-)  Reading over some of the comments made it clear that the OP's argumentative tone wasn't helping us understand the question.  RE: "write to blog" we need to remember that Yannis is just a mod and not in a good position to remember all the options SE offers.  :-P  Apparently his cybernetic upgrade hasn't fully taken yet, so he's still fallible.  To be fair, the earlier revs were ranty which is what blogs are for.  Latest rev lands squarely in the "self-answer is an option" category.

Comment: @gnat Hm, I suggested a self answer both in comments and in chat, and completely forgot about it here...

Comment: just found a wonderfully relevant suggestion in a recently introduced [instant-self-answer MSO tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/instant-self-answer/info) wiki: _...This feature is intended to promote the **"blog"** segment of the Stack Exchange mission statement by letting users post a self-answer without the awkwardness of seeing someone else get in an answer first._